# FortesReport no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Alguém teria alguma mini aplicação para eu ficar sabendo do funcionamento do Fortes Report?

Eu já fiz um relatório com o fortes report, porém o que estou me enganchando, é que eu tenho que colocar uma `Bane SubDetails` para eu tentar referenciar 2 querys no mesmo relatório e não estou sabendo fazer isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então vcs vêem o `Valorpago` e o `Troco` logo em baixo, eles são o que eu quero que pegue de outra query.
Ex.:todos os valores acima, são da `query4` e os de baixo, justamente os 2 de baixo são da `query7`.

A partir desta função abaixo, ela me retornaria os valores citados.(`Valorpago` e o `Troco`).

Código:

```
AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
  Reset(txt);
  while not eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, lTemp);

    if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E01') then
    begin
      date1 := StrToDateTime(copy(lTemp, 134,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp, 132,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp, 128,4));
      date2 := StrToDateTime(copy(lTemp, 142,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp, 140,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,
      136,4));
      date1treg := FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd', date1);
      date2treg := FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd', date2);
    end;
    if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E21') then
    begin
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.Close;
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.SQL.Clear;
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM finafim WHERE ccf= :ccf AND ' +
        'numcup= :coo AND impcaixa= :ecf AND descfina= :formpag AND vlfina= ' +
        ':valorfinal AND chfina= :pchfina AND dtcomp BETWEEN "'+date1treg+'" ' +
        'AND "'+date2treg+'"');
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('ccf').AsString := copy(lTemp, 53, 6);
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('coo').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('ecf').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('formpag').AsString := copy(lTemp,65,15);
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('valorfinal').AsFloat := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp,80,13))/100;
      DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.Open;


      if (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('ccf').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('ccf').AsString)
      and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('coo').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString)
      and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.ParamByName('ecf').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('impcaixa').AsString)
      then
      begin

        if (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('descfina').AsString = 'DINHEIRO')
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('chfina').AsInteger = 1)
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('numcup').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery4.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString)
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery4.FieldByName('ccf').AsString)
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('impcaixa').AsString =
          DModuleGrid.ZQuery4.FieldByName('NSerie').AsString)
        then
        begin
          frmDivIt.RLDBText13.DataField := 'vlfina';
        end;

        if (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('descfina').AsString = 'TROCO')
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('chfina').AsInteger = 91)
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('numcup').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery4.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString)
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery4.FieldByName('ccf').AsString)
        and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery7.FieldByName('impcaixa').AsString =
          DModuleGrid.ZQuery4.FieldByName('NSerie').AsString)
        then
        begin
          frmDivIt.RLDBText14.DataField := 'vlfina';
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  CloseFile(txt);
```

Além disso, o SubDetail não recebeu nenhum dado.

Comment: Acho que você deveria fazer uma pergunta mais específica. Atualmente ela está muito abrangente. Digo, qualquer exemplo do Fortes responderia sua pergunta, mas não lhe ajudaria. Da forma que está, a pergunta seria melhor colocada num fórum. No caso, sugiro você especificar as querys e o layout que será utilizado.

Comment: @EMBarbosa, ok cara! Vou fazer isto agora, editarei minha pergunta original!

Comment: Você linkou os `datasets` nas bandas corretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro um comentário sobre sua arquitetura.

Tente condensar seu relatório em uma query, provavelmente você está deixando a informação redundante.

Voltando ao assunto, encontrei [aqui](http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/download/4082/arquivo/relat%C3%B3rio-com-agrupamento-usando-o-fortes-reports) um exemplo mestre-detalhe pro Fortes Reports.

PAS:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
    0:begin
        ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames :='City';
        RLGroup1.DataFields := 'City';
        RLLabel1.Caption := 'City';
        RLDBText1.DataField := 'City';
      end;
    1:begin
        ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames :='State';
        RLGroup1.DataFields := 'State';
        RLLabel1.Caption := 'State';
        RLDBText1.DataField := 'State';
      end;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RadioGroup1.OnClick(Sender);
  RLReport1.Preview();
end;

procedure TForm1.RLDBText1BeforePrint(Sender: TObject; var Text: String;
  var PrintIt: Boolean);
begin
  if PrintFirst then
  begin
    PrintIt := true;
    PrintFirst := false;
  end
  else
    PrintIt := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.RLGroup1AfterPrint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrintFirst := true;
end;
```